# how to deploy an application created with svelte and sveltekit on a local apache server

Tags: apache, xampp, svelte, sveltekit

the application I am creating should be run on a local network with stack like xampp (apache web server and PHP-MySQL backend), where the base folder is htdocs and my project should be placed in a subfolder.
with the application created with svelte I changed the href of the build files .css and .js and everything works, but when I try the one created with sveltekit I can't.
How should I set the environment variables?